# What UIKit component would be used to make a popup like this?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

[image]

I think there is a default one but I can't seem to find the exact wording to find it in a search

Comment: The is an ActionSheet from a UIAlertController

Answer (score 1):

Thats a [UIAlert Actionsheet](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller).

They are a type of UIAlert that allows the alert to come up from the bottom, instead of appearing in the center of the view like traditional alerts.

Comment: Links can easily stop working. Please update your answer with the relevant information from the links.

Answer (score 1):

```
func showAlert() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(
            title: nil,
            message: "Choose a Radio Frequency",
            preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet)
        
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "5 GHz",
                                      style: UIAlertAction.Style.default,
                                      handler: {(_: UIAlertAction!) in
 
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "2.4 GHz",
                                      style: UIAlertAction.Style.default,
                                      handler: {(_: UIAlertAction!) in
 
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Annuller".localize(), style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: { _ in
            //Cancel Action
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```